# Invalid input syntax for integer when using HasOne in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm making a one-to-one relation in laravel 5.1 but when i run it I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "02.09" (SQL: select * from "category" where "category"."category_pos" in (02.09, 02.08, 02.06, 01.08, 02.11, 01.06, 02.02, 01.02, 2, 1) and "category"."deleted_at" is null)
```

Is there a way to convert `local_key` to string? E.g. 02.09 to `"02.09"`?

Comment: Will you add query code in question?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. It seems that I found my problem. I was trying to create hasOne to a integer field in db witch was the wrong field. When i change it to the proper field witch is string all worked fine.